# Cannot get SCVMM Admin Console to Connect to Hyper-V Server 2008 R2

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, system-center, scvmm

I cannot get SCVMM Admin console to connect to Hyper-V Server 2008. I have changed all firewall settings on the server to allow for a connection, I have even tried turning the firewall off completely. I am getting this error message:

**Unable to connect to the Virtual Machine Manager server xx.xxx.xxx.xx. the Virtual Machine Manager service on that servier did not respond.**

**Verify that Virtual Machine Manager has been installed on the server and that the Virtual Machine Manager service is running. Then try to connect again. If the problem persists, restart the Virtual Machine Manager Service.**

**ID: 1602**

I have tried restarting the VMMS service, and that did not work. I have posted a similar question to this before, and was told to make sure to intall the Hyper-V agent on the Hyper-V server. I was told that SCVMM can push the agent out to the server. However, if I cannot connect to the server, how can I use SCVMM to push out the agent?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What error are you getting when pushing the Agent? Did you follow [these directions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917923.aspx)? Have you tried [manually installing the agent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc764218.aspx)? The SCVMM Admin console will never connect to the server if the agent isn't installed, error 1602 simply means it can't contact the agent. Are you an admin on both the SCVMM machine and the Hyper-V machine?

Answer (score 2):

I was confused on the Microsoft terminology. I was trying to connect directly to Hypyer-V server with the admin console alone. I had not installed the VMM Server on the computer I was using the admin console on. Once I installed the VMM Server, I used the admin console to connect to localhost:8100 and it worked beautifully.